# Blender won't render on Dual / Single GTX 980

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

Recently, I've finished building my new Desktop. First thing I did was to install Blender and render a complex poly old project of mine. But Blender won't render on my Dual GTX 980, not even on single GTX 980. I've tried everything, but I can't get it to work.

Can somebody help me?

P.S : I've already tried the " Set it on Experimental " thing, but no luck.

Comment: What happens when you try to render?

Comment: Blender enters in render screen, but that's it, nothing renders.

Comment: Sounds like your GPUs might be running out of memory. Is there any output in the console?

Comment: Nothing. BTW, I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: This could be a case of your drivers being too new for the API that Blender is compiled against.  Something like that was happening a few months ago with people who bought really new cards.  I mentioned this question on IRC #blendercoders but you should file a bug report if nothing else works so it can be fixed as soon as possible if this actually is the problem.(BTW, when this happened before it was fixed within a week so I would not worry too much about it)

Comment: Actually it's a known problem, due to changes in latest CUDA kernel compiling for GTX 970 / 980. You can try to copy the file 2.72/scripts/addons/cycles/lib/kernel_sm_50.cubin to another in the same folder, named "kernel_sm_52.cubin". Or you can wait for the release of Blender 2.73...

Comment: Polosson - It worked! Thank you. I'm very pleased with the results. Dual GTX 980, Resolution 1920x1080 - 75%, Samples - 2.500. Project - Sculpted Mesh : 1.5 million Verts, 3 million Faces. Final time : 10 minutes